# how go to next page in man page

Tags: linux

```
SEE ALSO
     scp(1), sftp(1), ssh-add(1), ssh-agent(1), ssh-argv0(1), ssh-keygen(1), ssh-keyscan(1), ssh-vulnkey(1), tun(4),
     hosts.equiv(5), ssh_config(5), ssh-keysign(8), sshd(8)
```

I want know how to page ssh-keygen(1) . Which hotkey that i must use .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man` being piped through `less` has no way to generate much less follow any such links. You will need to invoke `man 1 ssh-keygen` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `man2html` package. Use `hman` to view man pages, e.g. `hman hman`.